# Is Flutter works for system activities like in Android?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I have a project in Android Studio, in which I implemented custom default dialer, dialing screen (features like mute, loudspeaker, hold, keypad, etc. during a call), play sounds from earpiece during a call. I also implemented services like the broadcast listener, integrated it with Firebase Machine Learning.  I want to shift to Flutter, is Flutter mature enough where I can perform such types of activities or I should go for Native apps only?
Thanks

Comment: Since Flutter is actually a "portable UI framework", these things will actually be done by native code, but might be possible with the existing libraries, that form a shared interface to be used in Flutter

Comment: Just to clarify, you've implemented, in Android (Java/Kotlin), a custom phone app, that can manage calls. And you want to know if you can do the same in Flutter with access to all the same native io?

Comment: @dumazycan you share those libraries?

Comment: @JoãoSoares Yes, I want to implement it in Flutter